# How can I add an existing AKS to AAD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-container-service, azure-aks

Some days ago Azure published a description on [how to create an AKS cluster with RBAC and AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration). I already have an AKS. How can I add an existing AKS to AAD?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If I go to https://resources.azure.com and check my AKS cluster created with Azure Active Directory (AAD) RBAC, I can see these properties related to such integration:

```
"enableRBAC": true
```

and

```
"aadProfile": {
  "clientAppID": "7ee598bb-0000-0000-0000-83692e2d717e",
  "serverAppID": "7ee598bb-0000-0000-0000-83692e2d717e",
  "tenantID": "72f988bf-0000-0000-0000-2d7cd011db47"
}
```

If I then go to https://resources.azure.com and try to change the property **enableRBAC** to **true** in another AKS cluster I have that was not created with AAD integration I get this error:

> {   "code": "InternalOperationError",   "message": "An error has
>   occurred in subscription 12a6d3bd-xxxx-xxxx-accf-0c984bed2311,
>   resourceGroup: aks request: existing ManagedCluster has
>   properties.enableRBAC false. update to true is not supported." }

So it looks like currently is not possible to add AAD support to an existing cluster - you will need to re create the cluster with AAD support.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Because to do this update on the cluster you would need access to the master nodes, which by definition you don't have in AKS.